# Checking HEAD from NSMutableURLRequest without Error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm working on a program for the iPhone and I ran into a bit of a snafu. I want to load a URL into a WebView, however, I want to make sure that the URL actually exists and is working before trying to load it into the view.

Imagine you have 200 servers and you know your file exists you just don't know which server. It is at http://serverXXX.mydomain.com/myfile.html where XXX is the server # 0 through 200

I wrote a bash script that uses cURL to loop through the servers checking the HEAD request of each iteration of the url and timing out after 1 second:

```
http://server1.mydomain.com/myfile.html
http://server2.mydomain.com/myfile.html
...
http://server199.mydomain.com/myfile.html
http://server200.mydomain.com/myfile.html
```

When it gets back a response it greps the response and compares it. If the response is OK it loads the URL in an external program and exits the script. How do I do this in Objective-C without the error "The requested URL was not found on this server." popping up?? I don't want to click OK 200 times while it tries to find the correct URL.

Comment: IMO, you should resolve this problem on the server. It seems irrational to have a mobile device query 200 servers for a file.

Comment: It may sound irrational but this program is for me, it is not for release. There is NO way to resolve the problem on the server. I don't know where the file is going to be on a day to day basis as it constantly bounces around.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same as your script with an instance of `NSMutableURLRequest` and a `NSURLConnection`. You can set the request to HEAD (`setHTTPMethod:`) and iterate over the server URLs updating the request after each response (`connection:didReceiveResponse:`) is received.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example of the code? I'm not too familiar with NSMutableURLRequest and its proper use.

Comment: Basically you're just creating an instance and then calling the method to set the method. Then set the URL each time and pass it to a new connection. Make yor class the delegate of the connection.

Comment: Google nsurlconnection example for additional details if required